# where to find the example source code in broadcast_state guide

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading through https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html

But I didn't find where to get the example source code used in this guide,could someone point it to me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a slightly improved version of that example in the [Flink training exercises repo](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/examples/datastream_java/broadcast/BroadcastState.java).

Comment: Thanks David for the helpful link!